# Flexible main landing page

Tags: css, html

I wanted to create an html page where I want a full screen image on the first section.

```
<header>
 <div class="menu"> </div>
 <div class="logo"></div> <div class="sub-menu"></div>

 <div class="main-banner"></div>
 <div class="bottom-menu-bar"></div>
</header>
```

Here, I want the `main-banner` to be flexible according to the screensize. This image should auto-adapt to the screensizes. The `bottom-menu-bar` should be always at the bottom of the splash page (first view section of a loaded webpage) but go up as we scroll down along with the main banner.

How can I achieve this? (A good example is PayPal website-though I inspected the elements but hard to understand it. Any quick and easy way?)

Thanks for your help. If Any information is needed, just let me know. I found similar questions some other websites but not a clear answer.

Comment: Showing the CSS you've already tried would make it easier to answer this question.  A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help too.

Comment: Paypal example doesn't seems to show the bottom-menu-bar feature as I understand. Also, do you want the element stay totally fixed (with content scrolling below?)

Answer (score 0):

To get the bottom-menu-bar to stay at the bottom of the page add this css:

```
.bottom-menu-bar{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

To get the main banner to be resizable use `width:100%;` instead of an explicit width like 600px.